# Shiny plot not showing full output

Tags: r, shiny

I made a very basic shiny app which can be found here: https://tejaykodali.shinyapps.io/taxiTrips

For some reason, it won't display output beyond hour 20, even if I set the ending hour as 23.

This is the function that generates the plot:

```
tripsPlot <- function(day, startHour, endHour) {
  tripsData <- subset(taxiData, Day == day)
  tripsTable <- table(hour(tripsData$tpep_pickup_datetime))
  tripsTable <- tripsTable[startHour + 1:endHour + 1]
  taxiPlot <- plot(tripsTable, type = 'o', xlab = 'Hour', xlim = c(startHour, endHour))
  return(taxiPlot)
}
```

The full code is here: https://github.com/ginobili0/taxiTrips

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you should change the line

`tripsTable <- tripsTable[startHour + 1:endHour + 1]`

to

`tripsTable <- tripsTable[(startHour + 1):(endHour + 1)]`.

The colon operator has higher precedence than the plus operator (in **R** see `?Syntax` for reference).

Edit:

The other problem is that `tripsTable` is a `table` (at first), which a is one-dimensional vector and is enumerated by the attribute `dimnames` (see `attributes(tripsTable)`), but when you subset it in the lines above you are returned an `array` object. Hence, `plot` does not pick the `table`method (`plot.table`). Ultimately, `plot` takes the one-dimensional vector and plots them along 1 to x (since it does not respect the `dimnames` attribute). There is two solutions, the shorter one being modifying

`tripsTable <- tripsTable[(startHour + 1):(endHour + 1)]`

to

`tripsTable <- as.table(tripsTable[(startHour + 1):(endHour + 1)])`.

By that we make sure that `tripsTable` is again an object of class `table` so that `plot` takes the corresponding method.

You could also make a new data frame with with proper `x` and `y` values (`x` being the hours) like so...

`tripsTable <- data.frame(seq(startHour, endHour, 1), tripsTable)`.

Comment: When I do that, the last two points are truncated in the plot. For example: if I select 3 to 14, it shows only 3 to 12.

Comment: Strange, because when I copy the code from your repository and apply my suggested change it is working just fine. When I choose 3 as starting hour and 14 as ending hour, the x-limits in the plot are just that: 3 to 14.

Comment: It worked after I converted it to a table! Thank you!